# DelayQueue with higher speed remove()?

Tags: java, performance

I have a project that keeps track of state information in over 500k objects, the program receives 10k updates/second about these objects, the updates consist of new, update or delete operations.

As part of the program house keeping must be performed on these objects roughly every five minutes, for this purpose I've placed them in a `DelayQueue` implementing the `Delayed` interface, allowing the blocking functionality of the `DelayQueue` to control house keeping of these objects.

- Upon new, an object is placed on the `DelayQueue`.
- Upon update, the object is `remove()`'d from the `DelayQueue`, updated and then reinserted at it's new position dictated by the updated information.
- Upon delete, the object is `remove()`'d from the `DelayQueue`.

The problem I'm facing is that the `remove()` method becomes a prohibitively long operation once the queue passes around 450k objects.

The program is multithreaded, one thread handles updates and another the house keeping. Due to the `remove()` delay, we get nasty locking performance issues, and eventually the update thread buffer's consumes all of the heap space.

I've managed to work around this by creating a `DelayedWeakReference (extends WeakReference implements Delayed)`, which allows me to leave "shadow" objects in the queue until they would expire normally.

This takes the performance issue away, but causes an significant increase in memory requirements. Doing this results in around 5 `DelayedWeakReference`'s for every object that actually needs to be in the queue.

Is anyone aware of a `DelayQueue` with additional tracking that permits fast `remove()` operations? Or has any suggestions of better ways to handle this without consuming significantly more memory?

Comment: Just curious... but what is this for (other than the technical problem)?

Comment: It's an engine for processing the contents of firewalls state tables, it takes a textual output from a firewall and reconstructs the state table in memory. This allows you to do much manipulation and analysis, and more importantly exporting information in other formats regularly, exporting the difference since the last update, as used in NetFlow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

took me some time to think about this, 
but after reading your interesting question for some minutes, here are my ideas: 
A. if you objects have some sort of ID, use it to hash, and actually don't have one delay queue, but have N delay queues. 
This will reduce the locking factor by N. 
There will be a central data structure, 
holding these N queues.  Since N is preconfigured, 
you can create all N queues when the system starts.

Comment: This is an interesting approach that I hadn't considered, sharding the `DelayQueue`'s. It would be easy enough to allocate objects to different ones using modulus, as they do all have a unique ID. This might be one way to scale.

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly what I meant. I would appreciate if you can test this, and if it helps, upvote :)

Comment: This is my best bet in the short term, and will probably scale well enough to meet my needs in the short to medium term. I may attempt to engineer a more specialised Queue for my own needs that provides the functionality required. -- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to perform a housekeeping "roughly every five minutes" this is allot of work to maintain that.

What I would do is have a task which runs every minute (or less as required) to see if it has been five minutes since the last update.  If you use this approach, there is no additional collection to maintain and no data structure is altered on an update.  The overhead of scanning the components is increased, but is constant. The overhead of performing updates becomes trivial (setting a field with the last time updated)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did consider doing a regular "full scan" of a `HashMap` rather then using a `DelayQueue`. However what I quickly realised was that it needed to be a anniversary for that specific object, i.e. they don't all share the same restrictions. I will run some tests on the performance difference of scanning say every five minutes, rather then a delay method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to do something to an object, if it hasn't been touched for 5 minutes.

You can have a custom linked list; the tail is the most recently touched. Removing a node is fast.

The book keeping thread can simply wake up every 1 second, and remove heads that are 5 minutes old. However, if the 1 second delay is unacceptable, calculate the exact pause time

```
// book keeping thread

void run()

  synchronized(list) 

    while(true)

        if(head==null)
            wait();
        else if(  head.time + 5_min > now )
            wait( head.time + 5_min - now );
        else 
            remove head
            process it


// update thread

void add(node)
  synchronized(list) 
    append node
    if size==1
        notify()  

void remove(node)
  synchronized(list) 
    remove node
```

Comment: The problem I suspect is searching for the object to remove in the `DelayQueue`, which internally uses a `PriorityQueue`, which in turn uses an `Object[]` to store. I wonder if a LL will be any quicker to search, or is the difference that it can be done without locking the whole structure?