# Efficiently update an element in a DelayQueue

Tags: java, performance, queue

I am facing a similar problem as the author in:
[DelayQueue with higher speed remove()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420915/delayqueue-with-higher-speed-remove)

**The problem:**
I need to process continuously incoming data and check whether the data has been seen in a certain timeframe before. Therefore I calculate a unique ID for incoming data and add this data indexed by the ID to a map. At the same time I store the ID and the timeout timestamp in a PriorityQueue, giving me the ability to efficiently check for the latest ID to time out. Unfortunately if the data comes in again before the specified timeout, I need to update the timeout stored in the PriorityQueue. So far I just removed the old ID and re-added the ID along with the new timeout. This works well, except for the time consuming remove method if my PriorityQueue grows over 300k elements.

**Possible Solution:**
I just thought about using a DelayQueue instead, which would make it easier to wait for the first data to time out, unfortunately I have not found an efficient way to update a timeout element stored in such a DelayQueue, without facing the same problem as with the PriorityQueue: the remove method!

Any ideas on how to solve this problem in an efficient way even for a huge Queue?

Answer (score 1):

This actually sounds a lot like a [Guava `Cache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained), which is a concurrent on-heap cache supporting "expire this long after the most recent lookup for this entry."  It might be simplest just to reuse that, if you can use third-party libraries.

Failing that, the approach that implementation uses looks something like this: it has a hash table, so entries can be efficiently looked up by their key, but the entries are also in a concurrent, custom linked list -- you can't do this with the built-in libraries.  The linked list is in the order of "least recently accessed first."  When an entry is accessed, it gets moved to the end of the linked list.  Every so often, you look at the beginning of the list -- where all the least recently accessed entries live -- and delete the ones that are older than your threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas! I will look into the Guava Cache. After writing the initial question I came up with the following idea: Instead of updating the timeouts in the queue, I will leave them untouched and only update the timeout elements in my Map stored along with the data. Upon retrieving the head of my queue, I check if the timeout is still the same as stored in the map, if not I will re-add the element to the queue. Therefore I can avoid removing elements explicitly from the queue other than just using poll()